# No cursor blinking(actually not visible only) in the Ubuntu's default text editor

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, reboot, cursor, text-editor

[image]I've installed Ubuntu dual boot(version 20.04 LTS) and when I opened the Ubuntu's default text editor, I didn't see any cursor blinking. I'm not talking about mouse pointer that is visible, only the cursor is not visible. Hence I'm unable to identify whether I gave spaces, line break and in which line I'm going to type. I've tried restarting and also saw a command on web `dconf reset -f /` which said it will reset default settings but still it didn't work.

Please help me bring it back or at-least how to restore defaults. I'm completely new to Linux and absolutely have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: I can confirm this. I use a different theme, where the current line is highlighted, but the cursor position is not marked.